# How to insert duplicated rows of different data into Database in PHP & HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql-server, database

This is example html  code i used. Basically, when I click 'Add New', the new row appear and I typed in the data. **But the problem is only the data of last row (if i add 3 rows, it is only inserting 3rd row's data) is inserting into database**

currently i used the simple sql query method to insert into database and I don't know how to modify the sql query or codes to make it store all the duplicated rows' data into databse.

If you can help me with this, it'd be most appreciated. Thanks !!
http://jsfiddle.net/2HGdv/13/ 
Here is how its work on jsfiddle.

one point is I don't use that `<? $i ?>` beside my variables in my actual html codes because when I add it, I got errors.

```
  <br>
        <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid">
            <tr>
                <th align="center">Roll No</th>
                <th align="center">First Name</th>
                <th align="center">Last Name</th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="rows">
                <div style="padding-left: 5px">
                    <td style="padding:5px;">
                        <input type="text" name="rollno<? $i ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:5px;">
                        <input type="text" name="firstname<? $i ?>" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="padding:5px;">
                        <input type="text" name="lastname<? $i ?>" />
                    </td>
                </div>
            </tr>
        </table>
            <br><div id="add_new">ADD NEW
</div>
```

This is the script for duplicating the rows.

```
$("#add_new").click(function () { 

    $("#maintable").each(function () {

        var tds = '<tr>';
        jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function () {
            tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        tds += '</tr>';
        if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
            $('tbody', this).append(tds);
        } else {
            $(this).append(tds);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overwrite your data because input attribute name remains the same. You need to make an HTML array that holds each row. Then in your js you will append one row with index the total `.rows` like `var total_rows = $(".rows").length;`

```
<form method="post" action="stack.php">
    <table id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="#729111 1px solid">
        <tr>
            <th align="center">Roll No</th>
            <th align="center">First Name</th>
            <th align="center">Last Name</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rows">
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[0][rollno]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[0][firstname]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[0][lastname]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rows">
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[1][rollno]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[1][firstname]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[1][lastname]" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div id="add_new">ADD NEW</div>
    <input type="submit" value="Save all items" name="saveButton">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['item']) && is_array($_POST['item'])) {
    $items = $_POST['item'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($items as $key => $value) {
        echo 'Item '.$i++.': '.$value['rollno'].' '.$value['firstname'].' '.$value['lastname'].'<br />';
    }
}
?>
```

So your next row will be the following:

```
<tr class="rows">
    <td style="padding:5px;">
        <input type="text" name="item[2][rollno]" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:5px;">
        <input type="text" name="item[2][firstname]" />
    </td>
    <td style="padding:5px;">
        <input type="text" name="item[3][lastname]" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: If you want any additional help let me know. Also if the solution i proposed helped you solving the problem please consider marking the answer as the accepted one.

Comment: It is still kind of not working unfortunately. I still have some problems with sql query while inserting into DB. Can u also help me with looping for the DB? I am really having a hard time. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't insert the items into the database. Can you show me how to insert? Thanks  a lot.

Comment: Could you open a new question providing the final code you use (html, php, sql data) and describing the problem? If so, inform me to check it because now i don't have all the data to be able to come up with an answer.

Comment: Hello. I have asked the new question. Thanks a lot for willing to help. I appreciate a lot. :)